# git workflow for two persons collaborating locally

Tags: git, version-control, workflow, dvcs

We're two people trying to get a new project up and running while working in one place and discussing our ideas at the same time.

1. git would be the preferred versioning system as I'm familiar with it
2. I'm using Linux while my colleague uses Windows
3. the lesser need for administration the better (we want to focus on coding)
4. we have an internet connection and a server (but keep 3. in mind)

A first idea was to host the code on [github](http://github.com) but as the code should remain private this is not an option, unfortunately. Another one was to use `git-daemon` to host one persons's repository locally in a centralized fashion.

Do you have any advice on best (and easy) practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple of options for doing everything locally to your network that don't take much administration.

#### Sharing a directory over SMB that contains a bare repository

How about getting your Windows-using colleague to share a directory over SMB, so you can mount it with Samba.  Then either one of you could just create a bare repository in that directory with:

```
cd shared
mkdir project.git
git init --bare
```

... and both push to and pull from that.

#### Accessing a repository on your computer with SSH

If you're happy to give your collaborator an account on your computer, you can easily create a shared bare repository that he can access with SSH.  If his user account is called `bob`, and you're `jnns`, that's just a matter of:

```
sudo groupadd gitusers
sudo adduser jnns gitusers
sudo adduser bob gitusers
sudo mkdir -p /srv/git/project.git
sudo chown jnns:gitusers /srv/git/project.git
cd /srv/git/project.git
git init --bare --group=shared
```

Then he can add a remote like this:

```
git remote add jnns-computer bob@whatever.local:/srv/git/project.git
```

... and you can just add the remote as:

```
git remote add local /srv/git/project.git
```

I don't think that counts as a lot of admin, but maybe opinions would vary on that :)

---

I feel I should also say that while you reject [GitHub](https://github.com/) as not being an option because you'd have to pay for private repositories, you really don't have to pay very much - I think $7 a month is a great deal for having private repositories on such a smooth service.

Comment: I want to add that we ended up using github's smallest plan for several projects now. But as of now, bitbucket also offers private git repositories, so that might also be an option for some.

Answer (score 2):

You could host your git repository on your server. It does not need a lot of administration.

Personally, when I don't have a server I use [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/) for my git repository. 2GB space available for free.

When DropBox is installed :

```
$ mkdir my_src_dir && cd my_src_dir
$ git init
```

After that, you can push your code on dropbox easily :-)

---

Other alternatives exist like [projectlocker](http://www.projectlocker.com/) as Navin Aggrawal said or [Codaset](http://www.codaset.com/).

*Codaset* :
Every single open source project you create is free, so come on and use Codaset at no cost. Your first private or semi-private project is also free.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of an inferior versioning system hosting a superior one :) Navin has some pretty valid points there.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of git hosting alternatives that are free if all you wanna do is get running fast:
http://www.projectlocker.com

I'm sure you've also realized that on your server you could set up a private git repo.

---

The only problem with using dropbox as SeyZ says above, is that you don't get versioning (so if you accidentally overwrite something, you are in trouble) -- and you also don't get branching both remote/local. I'd say stick with git ;)

If you really don't care about versioning though then go for dropbox, it's a nice service to use in general when you want to have files accessed by more than one person remotely.

Comment: I had a few problems with shared repositories in the past so I was hoping to get around puzzling over that. But I guess I have to face that once and for all. It seems obvious to host on our own server, at least.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the versioning ? You commit locally and you push on DropBox, so you have the versioning by Git ? If you have a problem, you can revert/checkout... without any problem.

Comment: Ohh I didn't fully realize what you were saying above. that makes sense! however, what if someone's dropbox syncs after another person made a code change? it seems like some potential conflicts could arise since the entire repo is being overwritten constantly...other than that, it's a valid way to work. quite creative, really